# The right encoding for `URLEncoder.encode`

Tags: java, scala, urlencode

I am trying to standardize the messages in my URLs and I am using `URLEncoder.encode`. The problem I get is that, the output does not seem to be a valid URL. For example

```
val text = Some("test question (a) x (b) y").get
val query = "http://localhost:8080/ask?text=" + text
println(query)
val queryEnc = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8")
println(queryEnc)
```

which outputs:

```
http://localhost:8080/ask?text=test question (a) x (b) y
http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fask%3Ftext%3Dtest+question+%28a%29+x+%28b%29+y
```

Is the output a valid URL? (it doesn't look to be valid, as Chrome and Safari on my machine don't recognize it).

Comment: From the Java doc: *"This class contains static methods for converting a String to the application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME format."* Is that what you want?  MIME?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You must encode each parameter value. Not the whole URL.

```
val query = "http://localhost:8080/ask?text=" + URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Always.Include.Namespace.Always